# Is there any way to transfer files from internet website to Google Docs directly?

Tags: google, google-drive

Suppose I have the file  `www.abc.com/temp.zip`.

Can I directly transfer it to Google Docs without downloading to the computer first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the dialog for uploads and copy+paste the address in the 'file-name' box, making sure to INCLUDE the http:// (or https://)

N.B. This will upload the zip, and not extract it. If you want the zip extracted first then you will need to download it to your pc and extract it before re-uploading all the files (AFAIK)

Comment: Can i give the list or more than one URL or it will work with single URL

Comment: I tried that it is taking too much time , for small files  in KB it works ok but not for big files. i think it first downloads those files and then upload

Comment: @Donkey AFAIK there is no other alternative

Answer (score 0):

I use a Chrome extension called [Cloud Save](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/omiekjeapoonbhiemenfoccbdpeagdah) which allows for downloading directly to a number of cloud services, including Google Docs.